# Is it safe to use a weak_ptr in a std::set or key of std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, weak-ptr

There have been a number of questions today regarding `std::weak_ptr` and `std::owner_less` and their use in the associative containers `std::set` and `std::map`.  There are a number of posts stating that using a `weak_ptr` in a `std::set` is incorrect, since if the weak pointer expires, it will be Undefined Behavior.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the reasons `std::owner_less` exists is to provide this ordering, and guarantee its safety in the presence of expiring weak pointers.  My logic is

First, the definition of `std::owner_less`

> - operator() defines a strict weak ordering as defined in 25.4
>
>   under the equivalence relation defined by `operator()`, `!operator()(a, b) && !operator()(b, a)`, two `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` instances are equivalent if and only if they share ownership or are both empty.

The two cases are

1. They share the same object, which in practical terms means they share the same reference count object.
2. They are both empty.

Now, I believe the confusion is over the second term.  The key is that "empty" in the standard means that the `weak_ptr` does not share ownership with any object.  Again, the standard states

> - `constexpr weak_ptr() noexcept;`
>
>   Effects: Constructs an empty `weak_ptr` object.
>      Postconditions: `use_count() == 0`.
> - `weak_ptr(const weak_ptr& r) noexcept;`
> - `template<class Y> weak_ptr(const weak_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;`
> - `template<class Y> weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;`
>
>   Requires: The second and third constructors shall not participate in the overload resolution unless `Y*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`.
>
>   Effects: If `r` is empty, constructs an empty
>     `weak_ptr` object; otherwise, constructs a `weak_ptr` object that shares
>     ownership with `r` and stores a copy of the pointer stored in `r`.
>
>   Postconditions: `use_count() == r.use_count()`.

Swap is defined as swapping the states of the two `weak_ptr`s, and assignment is defined as using the constructors above along with a swap.

They key to note here is that the only way to create an empty `weak_ptr` is to default construct it, or copy/move/assign one from a previously empty `weak_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.  It's also important to note that you cannot get an empty `weak_ptr` by simply letting the `weak_ptr` expire.  An expired `weak_ptr` simply has a `use_count` of zero.

As a practical matter, when a `shared_ptr` is created, a reference count object has to be created, either separate from the data using the `shared_ptr` constructor, or in the same memory allocation when `std::make_shared` is used.  When a `weak_ptr` is constructed from that `shared_ptr`, it will point to that same control structure and reference count.  When the `shared_ptr` is destroyed, it may destroy the data, but the reference count  object has to remain until all of the `weak_ptr` that share ownership are removed.  Otherwise, the `weak_ptr` would have a dangling pointer reference.

So, all of this taken together means that it is safe to use `std::weak_ptr` as they key of a `std::map` or in a `std::set`, as long as you use `std::owner_less` to perform the ordering.  The above guarantees that the ordering of the `weak_ptr` will remain the same even if it expires while it's in the container.

Comment: Can you add a conclusion to this answer ? :)

Comment: @Drax:  Sure thing.  I wrote this late at night and I missed little details like that.